# Android weight recording app with export/import

Tags: gratis, android, weight-tracker

A friend is using [Libra](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.cachapa.libra&hl) to record weight daily.

Apparently, a moving average is important. Also, no data should be sent to a company server (in fact, the fewer privileges the better; e.g mp access to contacts, 'phone, etc).

It seems that Libra's idea of exporting the data is to create a JPEG of a histogram.

An app is sought which will allow to export and then reimport the data into a different device. No requirements for a particular format, but, all other things being equal, then I would imagine that CSV, or even plain text would be preferable to some proprietary binary format.

Comment: As usual, you might wish to check with [my corresponding app list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/health_weight) for alternatives. Note that most of those apps ship with at least one, several at least 5, and some up to 11 trackers. Those shipping without are clear exceptions, and usually come from F-Droid. "Monitor your Weight" comes with 2 of those btw, and thus is at the lower end of the scale already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using [Monitor your Weight](http://monitoryourweight.com/) for ages. It allows export via email where a semicolon-separated list, similar to CSV is created which then you can email to yourself.

Which then you can copy to excel or a similar tool, I use Google Spreadsheets.

Sadly I don't quite understand the concept of moving average but it probably has it as it shows quite a lot of information.

I highly suggest it, it helped me a lot to lose weight.

[image]

[image]

Comment: wow! Over 20lb - more than 10% of your body weight! Gratz! Trend lien is probably as good as moving average. Btw, you might want to obscure your name in that pic ;-)

Comment: @Mawg this is not me, I've copied those images from their site. For reference, I've lost 55 kg (121 lbs) about 35% of my body weight in 6 months, running 10k almost every day and with the right diet.

Comment: Wah! Even more impressive!! Serious congratulations are in order. Stick with it.

Comment: A "moving average" is simply an average over the past _x_ period/entries, and as new entries are made, older entries "drop out" of the calculation - that is, the block of selected entries "moves" as new entries are added. For example, a 'five-day moving average' would take the average of the past five days (e.g., Monday through Friday, on Friday), and the first day would drop out on the sixth day (e.g., Tuesday through Saturday, on Saturday).

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Thanks for the explanation.